# SQL Server 2012 Adding a computed column to a view from another table with different data types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, type-conversion, calculated-columns

SQL newbie here. I have been researching how to add a computed column to a view with data from another table but the haven't been able to get my desired result.

Consider this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [Portfolio].[MTDPNL]
AS
SELECT IssuerLS, Issuer, Ticker, SUM (GLPeriod) As [PNL], ReportDate
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolioIssuerLS
WHERE ReportDate 
BETWEEN 
(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()), 120)) 
AND  
(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),(getdate()),120))
GROUP BY Issuer, Ticker, IssuerLS, ReportDate
```

Now consider this SELECT statement which returns a single integer value:

```
SELECT Nav AS [NavBOM]
FROM Portfolio.DailyStats ds
WHERE Date = (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()), 120))
```

I want to add a column to my view that is PNL/NavBom. In other words, for every row in my view, I want to add a column that takes the number from the PNL column as the numerator and divides it by the the NavBOM number (so the denominator is the same for every row)

I have been testing with the following code:

```
SELECT IssuerLS, Issuer, Ticker, SUM (GLPeriod) As [PNL], ReportDate, 
    CAST(SUM (GLPeriod)/(SELECT Nav AS NavBOM
    FROM Portfolio.DailyStats ds
    WHERE Date = (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()), 120))) 
    AS Decimal (7,4)) AS[%ofNAV]

FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolioIssuerLS

WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN 
    (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()),120)) 
    AND  
    (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),(getdate()),120))
GROUP BY Issuer, Ticker, IssuerLS, ReportDate
```

I'm not sure where the problem is but I'm getting a value of 0.0000 in the [%ofNAV] Column for every row. Both NavBOM and PNL are integer data types.. and since the NavBOM is going to be a much larger number compared to PNL, I need to convert it to decimal.

Also, the original view I created takes almost 4 seconds to execute. Probably because I have queries within my WHERE clause. Any suggestions to improve that will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Going from the bottom up... you can remove SELECT from the where clause though it's not going to be the performance killer. I assume ReportDate isn't of type Date or DateTime? Also what's the connection between your two tables. `DailyStats ` and `DailyPortfolioIssuerLS`?

Comment: ReportDate is of type Date (yyyy-mm-dd). 'DailyStats' and 'DailyPortfolioLS' doesn't really have a connection except that they both have performance number for the portfolio but 'DailyPortfolioLS' has that information at a more granular level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using CTE to get your NavBOM and then using it in your view creation.

```
CREATE VIEW [Portfolio].[MTDPNL]
AS
WITH cteNav as(
SELECT Nav AS [NavBOM]
FROM Portfolio.DailyStats ds
WHERE Portfolio.Date = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate()))

SELECT 
    IssuerLS, 
    Issuer, 
    Ticker, 
    SUM (GLPeriod) As [PNL],
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),GLPeriod)) /  CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),cteNav.[NavBOM]) as [%ofNAV]
    ReportDate
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolioIssuerLS
JOIN cteNav on 1=1
WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN  CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate())) AND getdate()   --interesting way to get the first day of the month BTW
GROUP BY 
    Issuer, Ticker, IssuerLS, ReportDate, cteNav.[NavBOM]
```

Comment: I got this error: Column 'cteNav.NavBOM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I tried to add the column to the GROUP BY clause after which the code executed but returned no data

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep sorry about that. edited to add to the group by

Comment: Still getting 0s in the [&ofNAV] Column. I think the issue is with the data type. We are dividing a number like 3500 by 35,000,000 for eg. I suspect converting the data type to something like decimal (7,4) will fix the issue

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep I didn't know it was an INT. Yes, you need to convert your INT column to decimal to prevent truncation. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks scsimon, the code works with a little tweak:

```
WITH cteNav as(
SELECT Nav AS [NavBOM]
FROM Portfolio.DailyStats ds
WHERE ds.Date = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate())))


SELECT IssuerLS, Issuer, Ticker,  SUM (GLPeriod) As [PNL],
CAST(SUM(GLPeriod)As Decimal (12,2)) /  CAST(cteNav.[NavBOM] As Decimal (12,2)) as [%ofNAV], ReportDate
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolioIssuerLS ls
JOIN cteNav on 1=1
WHERE ReportDate 
BETWEEN  
CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-1),GetDate())) 
AND 
CONVERT(CHAR(10),(getdate()),120)  
GROUP BY Issuer, Ticker, IssuerLS, ReportDate, cteNav.[NavBOM]
GO
```